# Using a loop to run a program n amount of times

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am new to the C programming language. I am attempting to run the code below an N amount of times (based on the user input of "Enter amount of iterations"). I am trying to do this using a for loop (also tried with a while loop) but have been unsuccessful.

Whenever I run the code below, my terminal continuously repeats "Enter two float numbers:". I have to close the terminal and reopen it to try again. Does the issue have to do with my for loop? I am interpreting my for loop as: "a=0; if a > 0; increment a".  Is there a way I can set a limit for "if a > 0" or should I be using a while loop? If the user enters "3" for amount of iterations, I am expecting the program to ask "Enter two float numbers" 3 times (with the answer).

```
        float sum (float m, float n){
        return m+n;}
        int main() {   
        float x, y;
        int a; 
        printf("Enter amount of iterations: ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        for (int i; i < 0; i++) {
        printf("Enter two float numbers: ");
        scanf("%f %f", &x, &y);
        float su = sum(x,y);
        printf("%f and %f = ", x, y);
        printf("%f\n", su);}
        return 0;}
```

**CORRECT ANSWER** Formatted for readability:

```
float sum(float m, float n)
{
    return m + n;
}

int main()
{
    float x, y;
    int a;
    printf("Enter amount of iterations: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter two float numbers: ");
        scanf("%f %f", &x, &y);
        float su = sum(x, y);
        printf("%f and %f = ", x, y);
        printf("%f\n", su);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have very strange `for` loop: `for (int a; a > 0; a++)`, maybe write it in this way `for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)`?

Comment: Please don't use Pico-style indentation in C; it is very unorthodox and close to unreadable.  Also, white space is cheap; use it!  Please use Allman (my preferred style) or 1TBS (a lot of other people prefer it) — see Wikipedia on [Indentation Styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) for more information.

Comment: Moreover, `printf` has a buffer for temporal storage of your print data, until it's not filled enough, you may use `fflush(stdout)` after `printf` to avoid buffering your output.

Comment: Note that the `a` in the `for` loop is different from and unrelated to the `a` declared earlier in the code and set by the input operation.    The `a` in the `for` loop is not initialized; you can't tell how many times the loop will be executed.  A good compiler should warn you about redefining or shadowing `a`.

Comment: Thank you, J.S! Works perfectly.. first day studying C. Thank you to everybody for the guidance. I will not use Pico-style indentation in c anymore! :D

Comment: So you can format the correct answer for readability, but not worth formatting the incorrect answer for the same reason?

Comment: You are 100% right lurker, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should behave more like you would like it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static float sum(float m, float n)
{
    return m + n;
}

int main(void)
{
    float x, y;
    int a;
    printf("Enter amount of iterations: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input for iterations\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter two float numbers: ");
        if (scanf("%f %f", &x, &y) != 2)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read to floating point numbers\n");
            return 1;
        }
        float su = sum(x, y);
        printf("%f and %f = ", x, y);
        printf("%f\n", su);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that it checks that the input operations are successful, and reports errors on standard error (`stderr`).  The code uses a standard C `for` loop to count from 0 up to a limit — this is idiomatic C.  You should get used to using it.

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55962203/using-a-loop-to-run-a-program-n-amount-of-times/55962302#comment98575790_55962203), the `a` in the `for` loop is different from and unrelated to the `a` declared earlier in your code and set by the input operation. The `a` in the for loop is not initialized; you can't tell how many times the loop will be executed. A good compiler should warn you about redefining or shadowing `a`.

Answer (score 0):

for (i = 0; i < a; i++);  - answer provided by J.S!